# How to group same adjacent objects into an array (eg:[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4] to [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3],[4,4,4]])?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

For example, I have an array : [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4], I want a result that group the same adjacent objects into another array : [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3],[4,4,4]], how can I do that? I tried:

```js
const arr=[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4];
const result=[];
for(let i=0,j=1;j<arr.length;j++){
  if(arr[j-1]!=arr[j]){
    result.push(arr.slice(i,j));
    i=j;
  }
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Which I expect [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3],[4,4,4,4]] but I don't know why would it be [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3]] (missed the last group).

I also tried

```js
const arr=[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4];
const result=[];
for(let i=0,j=1;j<arr.length;j++){
  if(arr[j-1]!=arr[j] || j==arr.length-1){
    result.push(arr.slice(i,j));
      i=j;
  }
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

but the result is [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3],[4,4]], which missed a "4" at the last group.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Change `j < arr.length` to `j <= arr.length`.

Comment: `arr.slice(i,j)` slices from index `i` inclusive to `j` exclusive. Thus, in your second approach when `j == arr.length-1` and you do `arr.slice(i, j)` it will miss the last element

Answer (score 4):

You are not dealing with the last group. Your idea is obviously to push the last group (made of everything from i, included to j, excluded) when you find an element that is different from the previous.

But the last group has no follower different from the previous.

There are ways to solve that. For example

```js
const arr=[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4];
const result=[];
for(let i=0,j=1;j<=arr.length;j++){
  if(j==arr.length || arr[j-1]!=arr[j]){
    result.push(arr.slice(i,j));
    i=j;
  }
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Based on the fact that `||` is a lazy or. So if `j` is `arr.length` then `arr[j-1]!=arr[j]` would not be evaluated. Which avoids using an index out of bound. Even tho, in javascript, it would not be a big deal: `arr[j]` would then just be `undefined`, which is ok for us, unless `arr[j-1]` also is, that is unless `undefined` is a possible value of `arr` content.

You could also simply, after the loop, add every thing after the last `i` (but for that you need `i` to exist outside the loop, so the `let i=0` be done before the loop).

I don't spend to much time on that, I am sure that you'll have answer for many ways to do the task.
What  I mainly want to point out, is another possibility, taken from *"The Art of Computer Programming"*, and often overlook: a **sentinel**.

Since your problem is the particular case of last group having no successor, just add a successor.

```js
const arr=[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4];
const result=[];
arr.push('whateveraslongasitisnot4');
for(let i=0,j=1;j<arr.length;j++){
  if(arr[j-1]!=arr[j]){
    result.push(arr.slice(i,j));
    i=j;
  }
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Sure, that means altering `arr`. So it is not always feasible. But then it avoid the cost of testing `j==arr.length` at every iteration. Again, that is also avoidable by treating that special case after the group. So, I am not claiming sentinel is the only option, nor that it is the faster one. Just, that it worth to be known. As you can see, to the cost of just one line (adding the sentinel) I can keep your code as is.

Note that the simpler solution (the one given in comments by Marc), that is just letting `j` go to `arr.length` included, is implicitly a version of that: arrays in javascript have implicit `undefined` after all their elements. So, if, as my `whateveraslongasitisnot4`, `undefined` is not to be found in array, and especially not at the end, then, that implicit `undefined` acts as a sentinel. Not sure it was thought that way, but that is a way of seeing it.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple One Liner**, You can use the below code to get the result that you are expecting.

```js
const input = [ 1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,1,1]
const output = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  (acc.length && acc[acc.length-1][0] === curr)?acc[acc.length-1].push(curr): acc.push([curr])
  return acc
}, [])
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const x = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4]

y = x.reduce((a,c,i) => (c!==x[i-1] && a.push([]), a.at(-1).push(c), a), [])

console.log(y)
```

If the current element is not the same as the one in the prior index, create a new subarray.

Then, push the current element into the most recently created subarray.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check all the `array elements` one by one with group of an array.

Follow this code if you want to check the `current` element is the same as the `previous` element:

```js
    function groupAdjacentElements(arr) {
      if (arr.length === 0) {
        return [];
      }

      const result = [];
      let currentGroup = [arr[0]];

      for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === arr[i - 1]) {
          currentGroup.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
          result.push(currentGroup);
          currentGroup = [arr[i]];
        }
      }

      result.push(currentGroup); // Add the last group
      return result;
    }

    const inputArray = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4];
    const groupedArray = groupAdjacentElements(inputArray);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(groupedArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and check if the last array exist with a value.

```js
const
    array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4],
    result = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const last = acc.at(-1);
        if (last?.[0] === curr) last.push(curr);
        else acc.push([curr]);
        return acc;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would to slice the array as you did in the second snippet. To include the latest item I would prefer to slice the latest chunk after the loop. Since you don't need to check the latest chunk in the loop it would be a bit faster.

```js
const arr = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4];

const result = [];
let prevIdx = 0;
for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i] !== arr[i-1]){
    result.push(arr.slice(prevIdx, prevIdx = i));
  }
}
result.push(arr.slice(prevIdx));

document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```
` Chrome/117
--------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander slice   1.00x  |  x10000000  609  641  650  655  677
chrslg slice      1.10x  |  x10000000  672  688  700  702  728
KooiInc push      2.07x  |   x1000000  126  130  131  141  144
--------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const arr = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4];

// @benchmark KooiInc push
arr.reduce((a,c,i) => (c!==arr[i-1] && a.push([]), a.at(-1).push(c), a), [])

// @benchmark chrslg slice
{
const result=[];
for(let i=0,j=1;j<=arr.length;j++){
  if(j==arr.length || arr[j-1]!=arr[j]){
    result.push(arr.slice(i,j));
    i=j;
  }
}
result;
}

// @benchmark Alexander slice
const result = [];
let prevIdx = 0;
for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i] !== arr[i-1]){
    result.push(arr.slice(prevIdx, prevIdx = i));
  }
}
result.push(arr.slice(prevIdx));
result;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.prototype.at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) to get the result.

```js
const arr=[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const lastArr = acc.at(-1);
    
    if(lastArr?.at(-1) === curr) lastArr.push(curr);
    else acc.push([curr]);

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it's not adjacent values, it groups the same values

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev According to the expected result. User want to group values. *I want a result that group the same adjacent objects into another array : [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3],[4,4,4]]*

Comment: the key is `adjacent`. the OP doesn't want *all* values grouped, `[1,1,2,2,1,1]` should give 3 arrays

Answer (score 0):

As one liner:

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, ];
const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => 
  (acc.at(-1)?.[0] === curr && acc.at(-1).push(curr) || acc.push([curr]), acc), 
  []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```